# Throwing exception in Guvnor (Guided Editor Rule)

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, guvnor

I'm building a rules project using Guvnor. In one of my DSL, I've the follow "consequence" statement for wrong operations:

`[when]Error "{message}"=throw new Exception( "{message}" );`

If I use the DSL rule, writing all the rule with DSL sentences, it works perfectly. However, using the Guided Editor, this doesn't work and the validation says anything like that:

`[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: org.drools.spi.KnowledgeHelper.throw()] [Near : {... throw new Exception( "` ...

Someone knows what I need to do for this works? It's important because my project will be used by non-IT people.

Thanks.

---

The source code generated by the Guided Editor is very simple:

```
rule "exception test"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        eval( true );
    then
        throw new Exception( "error message" );
end
```

Comment: Just one comment: are you sure your DSL starts with `[when]` and not with `[then]`? Otherwise, the guided editor will only allow you to use that DSL sentence in the LHS of a rule and that will be a problem.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake when put the code sample here. My sentence is with "then".

Comment: Could you post the "Source Code" of your rule? There is an option in Guvnor to see the generated DRL rule without DSL.

Comment: Yes, I added the source code in the original message. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the use of DSL sentences but with the use of `'mvel'` dialect. It appears that Mvel doesn't like the throw Exception syntax. 
The solution is to use `'java'` dialect instead.

In order to do that, you must add `'java'` dialect option in your rule:

[image]

Unfortunately, as far as I remember, there is no global setting in Guvnor to use `'java'` dialect by default.