# How to resolve POJO dependency with DRL in Guvnor?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, guvnor

I have imported the DRL file and required pojo as individual jar file in guvnor. I could see the dependent classes appearing as fact for individual rule and Guvnor exposes those rules via URL. I use changeset to consume the URL and apply the rules for my data. When I do that, I get below exception message for all the class I imported in the DRL file.

> Unable to Analyse Expression
>
> [Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: org.drools.spi.KnowledgeHelper.***]

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define which version of Guvnor.

Comment: Hi, I use Guvnor 5.5.0 version and  Drools runtime is also 5.5.0

Comment: @Steve , can you please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: @Steve I have mentioned dialect as "java" and now the error message is gone. But I still did not succeed in what I m doing. I have a standalone drools app which has DRL file that validates my incoming data and flags the erroneous data. Say I have an user object to validate age & check eligibility for voting, In my DRL the user object will be imported and rule defined for age check. In case of erroneous message I will set something in user object itself. How do I make this whole thing available in Guvnor for runtime rule updation?

Comment: I suspect you may need to create a new question around that. :)  But essentially, Guvnor is just a store for the rules. You application needs to run separately and load in the rules from a remote Guvnor instance. Search the Guvnor docs for "knowledge agent". This is the piece provided by Drools, to automatically reload rules from Guvnor (or elsewhere) when they are changed.

Comment: @Steve Sure I will raise one more question on this(Please follow my questions as I need your help in resolving the issues :) ). And I have my code implemented with knowledgeAgent for rules reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the DRL, I'll take a guess. I suspect that you're using the 'mvel' dialect, but your DRL is doing things which assume the Java dialect. Try changing that. You can see an example of this here:

[Throwing exception in Guvnor (Guided Editor Rule)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194122/throwing-exception-in-guvnor-guided-editor-rule)

If you post the DRL, then I may well need to reconsider and change/delete this answer. :)